# ngstyle not fully applied

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the following code to create dynamic styles,

```
    $scope.styles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 16; ++i) {
      $scope.styles.push([
        {
          background: 'url(images/' + i + '.jpg);',
          'background-size': '100% 100%;',
          transition: 'all 1000ms linear 1000ms;',
          'z-index': 20
        },
        {
          background: 'url(images/' + (i * 2) + '.jpg);',
          'background-size': '100% 100%;',
          transition: 'all 1000ms linear 1000ms;',
          'z-index': 10
        }
      ]);
    }
```

And the HTML part,

```
  <div ng-repeat="i in range(16)" class="album">
    <a ng-style="styles[i][0]"></a>
    <a ng-style="styles[i][1]"></a>
    <!-- <a class="type1"></a> -->
  </div>
```

However, in chrome only the `z-index` part is applied, I don't really know why,

[image]

Anyone please take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. This is really tricky!

You cannot have the semicolon in the styles, e.g `background: 'url(images/' + (i * 2) + '.jpg);',` should be `background: 'url(images/' + (i * 2) + '.jpg)'` instead

Otherwise angular would just "ignore" it. Not sure if it's by design or a bug.

Comment: Thats really weird. Should be classified as a bug.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, semicolon is not a value, it's css operator. It's not angular, jquery also doesn't accept semicolon